# How to count nested json objects from a nested array in python

Tags: python, json

How can I get the sum of objects count inside all movements?

Currently I'm chewing without success on this snippet below, though all my attempts digging down the nodes fail.

```
import json

RESULTS = 'sample.json'
with open(RESULTS) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    results = data
print(len(results[0]['result']['movements'])) #Expected: 3
```

*sample.json*

```
[
  {
    "result": {
      "TempId": "369477387",
      "movements": [
        {
          "date": "2018-05-03",
          "credit": 100.0,
          "shorttext": "My<br/>Expense "
        },
        {
          "date": "2018-05-03",
          "debit": 200.0,
          "shorttext": "My<br/>F\u00dcR"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "result": {
      "TempId": "369477395",
      "movements": []
    }
  },
  {
    "result": {
      "TempId": "369477402",
      "movements": [
        {
          "date": "2018-05-07",
          "credit": 100.0,
          "shorttext": "My<br/>Expense "
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a *list comprehension* you can find out the number of `movements` from every element from *sample* list.

Then just apply `sum` method over `count` list in order to find out the sum.

```
count = sum([len(item['result']['movements']) for item in sample])
```

Output

```
>> count
3
```